# Update column of a table based on array of varchar in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table to which i have added a column varchar colorcode.

The table already has many rows. state of table after adding colorcode column is

```
id   name               location     colorcode
121  Royal Challengers  Bangalore     
122  Sun Risers         Hyderabad
123  Dare Devils        Delhi
124  Gujrat Lions       Ahmadabad
```

I have a array of color codes

```
 ["#FF8484", "#FF82A9", "#FA82FF", "#C682FF", "#8782FF"]
```

For each row in the table I must update the colorcode column by matching index of array with (row_number() - 1).

I have dealt with list of values when using "in" clause.

example:

```
select * from table where id in(1,2,3,4) etc
```

here 1,2,3,4 is nothing but a array

I want to update the colorcode column on similar lines but I don't know how to access the elements of my array based in index.

after running the update statement my expected output is

```
id   name               location     colorcode
121  Royal Challengers  Bangalore     #FF8484
122  Sun Risers         Hyderabad     #FF82A9
123  Dare Devils        Delhi         #FA82FF
124  Gujrat Lions       Ahmedabad     #C682FF
```

I can sort the result based on id ie., the primary key

Note: I am using Postgres

Comment: What is the expected outcome of the update? Why do you need to refer to the previous row? And how is "previous" defined? On which attribute can you sort the rows? [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected result (_formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: I have edited the question and added the expected outcome of update. I need not refer to previous row. The row_number() - 1 is to make sure that the colorcode corresponds to array index  row_number() is 1 based and array indexes are 0 based(i think) so to compensate for that i am doing row_number() -1 . You can sort the rows based on id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as follows. I assume your table is called *t*:

```
update t
set    colorcode = middle.cc
from   (
        select id, ('{#FF8484,#FF82A9,#FA82FF,#C682FF,#8782FF}'::text[])[rn] as cc
        from   (select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from t) as base
        where  rn <= 5
       ) as middle
where middle.id = t.id;
```

In the most inner query (*base*), the row number is retrieved for each record in the table. Then in the middle query (*middle*) that row number is used to fetch the corresponding colour code from an in-line array of text elements. Finally the update statement joins that result with the table *t* again, by its *id*, in order to store that colour code.

Comment: @curiosa, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Brilliant answer @trincot  this is exactly what i was looking for